# CakePHP - Associations Problems

Tags: php, cakephp, forum, forums

I'm trying to make it so when I do a $this->Topic->find('all'), it will pull all the associated User data, and all the associated Post data. The problem is that I can't manage to do that right now.

Right now I do $this->User->find('all'), which returns the Topic data, and all Posts inside that Topic. I guess this is what my code *tells* it to do, but it's not what I want. Please forgive my explanation.. I **really** suck at CakePHP associations.

Here are my models for your reference:

Topic.php

```
class Topic extends AppModel {
var $name = 'Topic';

var $actsAs = array('Containable');                
var $hasMany = array(
    'Post' => array(
        'className'     => 'Post',
        'foreignKey'    => 'topicid'
    )
);

var $hasOne = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className'    => 'User',
        'foreignKey'    => 'id'
    )
);    

var $belongsTo = array(
    'Forum' => array(
        'className'    => 'Forum',
        'foreignKey'    => 'id'
    )
); 
}
```

Post.php

```
class Post extends AppModel {
var $name = 'Post';
var $actsAs = array('Containable');
 var $hasOne = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className'    => 'User',
        'foreignKey'    => 'id'
    )
 ); 


 var $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'userid'
 ),
    'Topic' => array(
        'className'    => 'Topic',
        'foreignKey'    => 'topicid'
    )
 );

}
```

Forum.php

```
class Forum extends AppModel {
var $name = 'Forum';

var $hasMany = array(
    'Topic' => array(
        'className'     => 'Topic',
        'foreignKey'    => 'forumid'
    )
);
}
```

User.php

```
class User extends AppModel {
var $name = 'User';
var $actsAs = array('Containable');


var $hasMany = array(
    'ForumPost' => array(
        'className'     => 'ForumPost',
        'foreignKey'    => 'userid'
    ),
    'ForumTopic' => array(
        'className'     => 'ForumTopic',
        'foreignKey'    => 'userid'
    )
);
}
```

I want it so that I can do $this->Topic->find('all'), and it gives me the Topic data, then the Post data for each Post in the Topic, and the User data for each Post in the Topic (respectively)..

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I found out my problem, thanks to savant in the #cakephp IRC channel. My models were named wrong.. :)